# Node.js application not retrieving data from the MongoDB database? Getting error registrations is not defined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Im getting the error registrations not defined when trying to retrieve data from the database and displaying it as a table. I can't seem to figure out why as my database does have documents in it.

I'm getting the error registrations not defined when I'm trying to retrieve data from the database and displaying it as a table

this is my adminRoutes.js:

```
// adminRouter.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Register = require('./registers');

// Admin login page
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render('adminLogin');
});

// Admin login form submission
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  // Check if the username and password are correct
  if (username === 'tennisadmin' && password === 'tennis2024') {
    res.render('adminDashboard'); // Assuming you have an adminDashboard.ejs file for the admin dashboard
  } else {
    res.render('adminLogin', { error: 'Invalid username or password' });
  }
});



router.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
  Register.find({}, (err, registrations) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error retrieving registrations:', err);
      res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    } else {
      console.log('Registrations:', registrations);
      res.render('adminDashboard', { registrations });
    }
  });
});





// Other admin-related routes can be added here

module.exports = router;
```

this is my adminDashboard.ejs:

```
// adminRouter.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Register = require('./registers');

// Admin login page
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render('adminLogin');
});

// Admin login form submission
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  // Check if the username and password are correct
  if (username === 'tennisadmin' && password === 'tennis2024') {
    res.render('adminDashboard'); // Assuming you have an adminDashboard.ejs file for the admin dashboard
  } else {
    res.render('adminLogin', { error: 'Invalid username or password' });
  }
});



router.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
  Register.find({}, (err, registrations) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error retrieving registrations:', err);
      res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    } else {
      console.log('Registrations:', registrations);
      res.render('adminDashboard', { registrations });
    }
  });
});





// Other admin-related routes can be added here

module.exports = router;
```

this is my register model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const playerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  registrationId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  Name: {
    type: String,
  },
  mobile: {
    type: Number,
    unique: true,
  },
  email: {
   type: String,
   unique: true,
   required: true,
   trim: true,
   lowercase: true,
 },
  dob: {
    type: String,
  },
  city: {
    type: String,
  },
  price1: {
    type: String,
  },
  namefirst: {
    type: String,
  },
  price2: {
    type: String,
  },
  namesecond: {
    type: String,
  },
  Size: {
    type: String,
  },
  Food: {
    type: String,
  },
  Drink: {
    type: String,
  },
  stay: {
    type: String,
  },
  payment: {
    type: String,
  },
});

const Register = mongoose.model("Register", playerSchema);
module.exports = Register;
```

Comment: I'm using version 6.3.0 . What would be the right way to retrieve the data then?@jQueeny